# Need explanation regarding the idea of two's complement

Tags: twos-complement

Can you please explain the solution for the below problem?
I do not understand how we arrive to this conclusion −2^(n−1) + 2^(n−1) −1 −x
Especially I am confused why we need to subtract x

*You obtain the representation for a negative number in two’s complement method by taking
one’s complement of a number and then adding one. Why does it work? What is the key idea behind two’s complement representation?*
Answer: The key idea is to treat the sign bit as a value with a negative sign. In a n-bit representation,
the value of the sign bit is -2^n1 .
When you have a positive number x. By taking two’s complement you want to get −x.
In a positive number x, the sign bit is 0. When you take the one’s complement of the number, you get:

−2^(n−1) + 2^(n−1) −1 −x

On simplification you get −x−1. When you add +1 to the number (as with two’s complement: take one’s complement and add one), you arrive at −x.
This provides a unique representation for zero. Further all the number calculations are according to powers of two unlike one’s representation for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you provided seems making explanation of One and Two's compliment unnecessarily complicated. Put it short, One's compliment is obtained by flipping all bits in the binary representation of the number. Let's say n = 8, x = 13, then in One's compliment

x = 00001101  (unsigned value 13)

-x = 11110010 (unsigned value 242 = 255 - 13)

i.e. -x is represented as 2^n - 1 - x

Two's compliment is simply One's compliment plus 1:

-x = 11110011 (unsigned value 243 = 255 - 13 + 1)

i.e. -x is represented as 2^n - x

Back to the solution you provided:

−2^(n−1) = 10000000

2^(n−1) −1 = 01111111

−2^(n−1) + 2^(n−1) −1 = 11111111

(−2^(n−1) + 2^(n−1) −1) - x flips all bits in binary representation of x, exactly what One's compliment does. IMO, this explanation is quite counter-intuitive, explanation above (or from Wikipedia) is much better ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question.  Two's complement is format used to make certain things easier and it only works when you're values are limited in some way (a fixed number of bits).  For 4-bit words, the one's complement of zero is 1111, to get two's complement you add a 1, which cascades flipping all the bits to 0000, that's convenient.  The one's complement of 0001 is 1110, add one and you get 1111, which when interpreted as a signed value is -1.

```
     1's     2's
2   1101   1110
3   1100   1101
4   1011   1100
```

The first (MSB) bit always indicates if the value is positive or negative.  The other values "count up" (1,2,3,4...) for positive values and "count down" (-1,-2,-3...) for negative values.

It's difficult to try to express this in non-discrete algebraic terms, because "numbers" as we generally think about them are infinite.